# EachProperty on Factory method with ConfigurationInject

Tags: micronaut

Trying to inject multiple singletons of `ThirdPartyClass` via `@EachProperty`.

Since I don't own `ThirdPartyClass` I am using `@Factory` for this purpose, like so:

```
@Factory
public class ThirdPartyClassFactory {
    @EachProperty("xyz")
    @ConfigurationInject
    public ThirdPartyClass thirdPartyClass(int a) {
        return new ThirdPartyClass(a);
    }
}
```

And configuration:

```
xyz:
  default:
    a: 5
  another:
    a: 9
```

But running this gives me

```
Failed to inject value for parameter [a] of method [thirdPartyClass]
No bean of type [int] exists. Make sure the bean ...
```

However if I would own `ThirdPartyClass`, following approach would work well:

```
@EachProperty("xyz")
public class ThirdPartyClass {
    @ConfigurationInject
    public ThirdPartyClass(int a) {
    }
}
```

Note, it's not that `@EachProperty` doesn't work on factory methods at all, I just couldn’t make it to inject properties like I would do with `@EachProperty` on class definition.

Could anyone shed a light on this? Probably I am just missing some documentation part.

Answer (score 0):

`ConfigurationInject` is not designed to be used in factory methods. Assuming the class isn't final you can extend it and place the annotations on the extension.

You can file an issue requesting support for this use case